# Brute force code to merge intervals - Google sheets appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, intervals, brute-force

I need a bruteforce code in appscript to merge the intervals into one or more intervals that contain all the ranges for an specific ID. I'm already working on it but in the actual state i cannot program in appscript and i'm hoping to get this task done as soon as possible.

Example: for ID 11403

```
{43896,44463} 
{44245,44245}
{44257,44257}
{44258,44258}
{44258,44258}
{44265,44316}
{44271,44271}
{44277,44279}
{44300,44326}
{44363,44363}
{44363,44363}
{44376,44376}
{44265,44316}
{44271,44271}
{44410,44410}
{44537,44537}
{44540,44553}
{44544,44547}
```

The results must be:

```
{43896,44410}
{44537,44537}
{44540,44553}
```

Sheet of use: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UR0xgjCHVxE2Vt0-teSK25f-Kej14Kwfhu5hyhXbDNg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: I see no logical way how from this data can be obtained this result.

Comment: Hey Yuri, i've updated the result, they truly were wrong, most specifically {43896,44410} was corrected to {43896,44463}. That's the expected results i'm looking for.

Comment: Where did you update the result. In spreadsheet? But there is no access by this link. In your question I see no changes

Comment: Here's the updated version ( <https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UR0xgjCHVxE2Vt0-teSK25f-Kej14Kwfhu5hyhXbDNg/edit?usp=sharing> ), the results you posted in you answer matches the ones i was searching for. And yes, i want it to loop trough the id's so each one of them returns it's own merged ranges.  Gonna give a try in the function you've sent in the answer, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your table looks like this:

| ID | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11403 | 43896 | 44463 |
| 11403 | 44245 | 44245 |
| 11403 | 44257 | 44257 |
| 11403 | 44258 | 44258 |
| 11403 | 44258 | 44258 |
| 11403 | 44265 | 44316 |
| 11403 | 44271 | 44271 |
| 11403 | 44277 | 44279 |
| 11403 | 44300 | 44326 |
| 11403 | 44363 | 44363 |
| 11403 | 44363 | 44363 |
| 11403 | 44376 | 44376 |
| 11403 | 44265 | 44316 |
| 11403 | 44271 | 44271 |
| 11403 | 44410 | 44410 |
| 11403 | 44537 | 44537 |
| 11403 | 44540 | 44553 |
| 11403 | 44544 | 44547 |
| 12345 | 43896 | 44463 |
| 12345 | 44245 | 44245 |
| 12345 | 44257 | 44257 |

Here is the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getRange('A2:C').getValues();

  var obj = {}
  while (data.length) {
    var [key, start, end] = data.shift();
    var range = {'start': start, 'end': end};
    try { obj[key].push(range) } catch(e) { obj[key] = [range] };
  }

  var ranges = merge_ranges(obj['11403']); // get the merged ranges for id 11403

  console.log(ranges); // <-------- here are the results (for id 11403)
}


function merge_ranges(obj) {
  var range = obj.shift();
  var end = range.end;
  var ranges = [range];
    
  while (obj.length) {
    var range = obj.shift();
    if (range.start > end) {
      ranges.push(range)
      if (range.end > end) end = range.end;
    }
  }
  return ranges;
}
```

From your data it gives the array of ranges:

```
[ { start: 43896, end: 44463 },
  { start: 44537, end: 44537 },
  { start: 44540, end: 44553 } ]
```

They look quite close to your results.

But it's not clear from your question what exactly you want to do with these results. Loop through all the IDs an put on the sheet?

**Update**

Probably it should be something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Página1'); // <----- a name of the source sheet
  var data = sh.getRange('A2:C').getValues();

  // create the object {id1: [range, range, range], id2: [range], ...}
  var obj = {}
  while (data.length) {
    var [id, start, end] = data.shift();
    var range = {'start': start, 'end': end};
    try { obj[id].push(range) } catch(e) { obj[id] = [range] };
  }

  // make the table from the object [id, range.start, range.end]
  var table = [];
  for (var id in obj) {
    var ranges = merge_ranges(obj[id]);
    ranges.forEach(range => table.push([id, range.start, range.end]));
  }
  
  // create or select the sheet 'Output'
  try { var output = ss.getSheetByName('Output'); output.clear(); }
  catch(e) { var output = ss.insertSheet(); output.setName('Output') }

  // add the header to the table and put the table on the sheet
  var header = ['ID', 'Start', 'End'];
  table = [header, ...table];
  var range = output.getRange(1, 1, table.length, table[0].length);
  range.setValues(table);
}

function merge_ranges(obj) {
  var range = obj.shift();
  var end = range.end;
  var ranges = [range];
    
  while (obj.length) {
    var range = obj.shift();
    if (range.start > end) {
      ranges.push(range)
      if (range.end > end) end = range.end;
    }
  }
  return ranges;
}
```

It puts the results as a plain 3-colon table on the sheet 'Output'.

Comment: As said in the comment above, that's exactly it. The results match the ones i need, and your supposition it's right too, i want it to loop and look through al the id's to return for each one it's specific range and then put them on the sheet. How would one adapt your code to do it? Thank you for the help

Comment: To put the result on the sheet it a quite trivial task. But it can be done many ways. It would be better if you show, how the result should look like.

Comment: The expected results are now in the table provided on this link 

[Sheet}<https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UR0xgjCHVxE2Vt0-teSK25f-Kej14Kwfhu5hyhXbDNg/edit?usp=sharing>

Comment: Yeah... ) Almost. I just added the variant that makes the result table exactly like in your example (3 columns) but it puts the table on a new sheet 'Output'. I can rewrite the code to put the table on the same sheet into columns E,F,G if you want. Shall I?

Comment: Oh, that's pretty nice of you, i truly thank you man.

You don't need to, maybe it's good for me to put at least some effort, i'll try to understand the code, you sure helped me a lot.